# How to terminate a program Java if you asked the user ("Enter a number (1-99) or press 0 to EXIT"), and the user entered 0?

Tags: java, methods, netbeans, computer-science

I created a program for my intro to programming class that lets you put in any number (1-99) which represents the amount of change you have, and it tells you how many quarters, dimes, nickles and pennies you have.  Example: 42 cents would be 1 quarter, 1 dime,  1 nickle, and 2 pennies).  Anyways I asked the user ("Please Enter Amount of Change (1-99) OR press 0 TO EXIT").  If they pressed 0, how would I code my program to terminate?  This is what I have so far:

//minimum amount of coins program

package minicoins;

/**
 * @author Casey Bunker
 * @date March 31, 2020
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Minicoins {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         //declare & initialize variables
        //Instantiating Scanner 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int change = 0;
    int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickles = 0;
    int pennies = 0;

    //asking user for input
    System.out.print("Please Enter Amount of change(1-99) or ZERO TO EXIT:");

    //take input from the user
    change = input.nextInt();

     //loop through program while user enters numbers, stop when they enter 0
    while (change!=0){
        while (change >= 25){
            change = change - 25;
            quarters=quarters+1;
        }
        while(change>=10){
            change = change - 10;
            dimes = dimes + 1;
        }
        while(change>=5){
            change=change-5;
            nickles = nickles + 1;

        }
        while(change>=1){
            change = change - 1;
            pennies = pennies + 1;
        }
}

    System.out.println("Quarters:"+quarters);
    System.out.println("Dimes:"+dimes);
    System.out.println("Nickles:"+nickles);
    System.out.println("Pennies:"+pennies);

}
```

}

Comment: Your code does terminate - what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Your program exits no matter what the user enters, so I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Could improve by `change = input.nextInt();  if (change <= 0) return;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.exit(0) to force exit from your program. find out more info here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-exit-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Before printing to the user, you can do something like this:

```
/*
your while loops
*/
if (change == 0){
    System.out.println("exiting...");
    System.exit(0);
}
/*
your prints
*/
```

EDIT:
You can actually exit the program by typing return instead of System.exit(0). But System.exit(0) is a more general way because if you are not returning from the main() function, then your program won't actually exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ahmed's answer but instead of putting it after the while loop, put it after you get the user input which is

```
 change = input.nextInt();
```

That will prevent the program to do the calculations inside the while loop since you don't need the code to do that anymore. Here's the final code you can use.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     //declare & initialize variables
    //Instantiating Scanner 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int change = 0;
    int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickles = 0;
    int pennies = 0;

    //asking user for input
    System.out.print("Please Enter Amount of change(1-99) or ZERO TO EXIT:");

    //take input from the user
    change = input.nextInt();

    if (change == 0) {
        System.out.println("exiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {

        //loop through program while user enters numbers, stop when they enter 0
        while (change!=0){
            while (change >= 25){
                change = change - 25;
                quarters=quarters+1;
            }
            while(change>=10){
                change = change - 10;
                dimes = dimes + 1;
            }
            while(change>=5){
                change=change-5;
                nickles = nickles + 1;

            }
            while(change>=1){
                change = change - 1;
                pennies = pennies + 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Quarters:"+quarters);
        System.out.println("Dimes:"+dimes);
        System.out.println("Nickles:"+nickles);
        System.out.println("Pennies:"+pennies);
    }

}
```